# What's the point of the [comparison] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comparison) tag has 3.8k questions, and only 15 followers.

The description begs it be used for "data comparison" questions, and not "comparison of two issues or concepts", though almost invariably it seems to be the latter, e.g. ["Difference between" questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232102/difference-between-assembly-zero-and-equal).

Is it really adding any worth?

If there are significant questions on data comparison that need this tag, why not have [data-comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-comparison) instead? This would almost certainly stop people using it for "comparison[s] of two issues or concepts".

Comment: "Comparison" could relate to any data comparison (including strings or whatever) but also comparison operators, as well as "number of comparisons", which is a way to measure algorithm effectiveness.

Comment: @Lundin is that a vote in favour of the tag? Just makes it sound vague and meaningless to me.

Comment: No, it's additional information without bias. Votes are cast with the little arrow buttons to the left...

Comment: Note - the [tag:data-comparison] tag *already* exists.

Comment: @Dukeling Excellent point. Although it has only 25 questions - it shows that people with legitimate [data-comparison] in mind are using it. I don't believe it's an "artificial complication" as Bergi calls it.

Answer (score 4):

> why not have [data-comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-comparison) instead?

There's no need to artificially complicate a tag name. There won't be a meta-tag for the question type, so we do not need to distinguish. The warning in the excerpt should be enough.

> almost invariably it seems to be a comparison of two issues or concepts

Not from what I can see. Most of the questions that are tagged [comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comparison) do handle comparison (including equality/identity-test) operators and functionality.

Of course, some of them are also asking for a comparison between concepts, [Differences in string compare methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288/differences-in-string-compare-methods-in-c-sharp) is a good and clear example for that. Even the one you mentioned, [Difference between assembly zero and equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232102/difference-between-assembly-zero-and-equal), is about comparisons done in assembly and why there are different instructions to handle the comparison results (status flags).

If you see a question that definitely does not deal with comparing values, simply **untag it**.

Comment: You seem to think most people actually read the excerpt. Proof they don't - `"DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!!"` appears in the [tag:api] tag, yet it managed to get ~40 new questions just today. There are many, many other similar examples.

Comment: Yes, I think that *most* people do - it shows up very prominent in the autocomplete suggestions. Of course, there are always *a few* who don't, but I hope they are a minority. And we wouldn't rename it to [tag:too-generic-api] only for them either, would we?

Comment: "DO NOT USE.." is an entirely separate issue. I would love to know why such tags are not either deleted, or locked by moderator (facility created by dev if not possible), but that's another question.

Comment: Ok, that's proof that plenty of people don't. Most? Who knows. Bottom line - there will likely be plenty of misuse, most of which could likely be avoided by just replacing [tag:comparison] with [tag:data-comparison], and this won't have a particularly significant disadvantage.